# PHP - Executing a function depending on which variable is called

Tags: php, function

I have 2 functions that do the exact same thing but for different variables:

```
function checkRights($user){
    if($user['rights'] == 'DEVELOPER'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#9A9A9A";
        echo' <img src="/Developer.png" alt="Developer Icon"/>';
    } else if($user['rights'] == 'ADMINISTRATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#D0CE2C";
        echo' <img src="/admin.png" alt="Administrator Icon"/>';
    } else if($user['rights'] == 'MODERATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#FFCC00";
        echo' <img src="mod.png" alt="Moderator Icon"/>';
    } else if($user['rights'] == 'DONATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#FF0000";
        echo' <img src="donator.png" alt="Donator Icon"/>';
    } else if($user['rights'] == 'SUPER_DONATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#9A9A9A";
        echo' <img src="/superdonator.png" alt="Super Donator Icon"/>';
    } else if($user['rights'] == 'LEGENDARY_DONATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#9A9A9A";
        echo' <img src="/respecteddonator.png" alt="Legendary Donator Icon"/>';
    } else if($user['rights'] == 'PLAYER'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#037AAC";
    }
}
function checkPlayerRights($player){
    if($player['rights'] == 'DEVELOPER'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#9A9A9A";
        echo' <img src="/Developer.png" alt="Developer Icon"/>';
    } else if($player['rights'] == 'ADMINISTRATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#D0CE2C";
        echo' <img src="/admin.png" alt="Administrator Icon"/>';
    } else if($player['rights'] == 'MODERATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#FFCC00";
        echo' <img src="/mod.png" alt="Moderator Icon"/>';
    } else if($player['rights'] == 'DONATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#FF0000";
        echo' <img src="/donator.png" alt="Donator Icon"/>';
    } else if($player['rights'] == 'SUPER_DONATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#9A9A9A";
        echo' <img src="/superdonator.png" alt="Super Donator Icon"/>';
    } else if($player['rights'] == 'LEGENDARY_DONATOR'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#9A9A9A";
        echo' <img src="/respecteddonator.png" alt="Legendary Donator Icon"/>';
    } else if($player['rights'] == 'PLAYER'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#037AAC";
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way I can combine them both into a function called `checkRights` so that all I have to do is execute one function but call which variable I want it to run the check.

For example: `checkRights($user);` or `checkRights($player);`

Comment: Yes, that is how functions work, pass it whatever you need. The variable inside the function has its own scope, you can call it what every you want in the definition. Also look at `SWITCH` statements, that could be easier to read.

Comment: Yes you can :-) and are already done as far as i can see. just remove the checkPlayerRights function.

Comment: They are the same function. The variable name doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a single function that takes one argument (which you had already done anyway):

```
function checkRights($obj){
    if($obj['rights'] == 'DEVELOPER'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#9A9A9A";
        echo' <img src="/Developer.png" alt="Developer Icon"/>';
    } 
    // ...
    else if($obj['rights'] == 'PLAYER'){
        $GLOBALS['crowncol'] = "#037AAC";
    }
}
```

Now call the function like so:

```
checkRights($player);
checkRights($user);
```

Comment: `$user` works fine. Code doesn't need to change at all. Just change the function call and OP is good to go..